# C# Regex remove sentences after some specific tab

Tags: c#, regex, sentiment-analysis

How do I write a regular expression to remove sentences after some specific tab?

For example My text in richtextbox

```
a   00001740    0.125   0   able#1  (usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something; "able to swim"; "she was able to program her computer"; "we were at last able to buy a car"; "able to get a grant for the project"
a   00002098    0   0.75    unable#1    (usually followed by `to') not having the necessary means or skill or know-how; "unable to get to town without a car"; "unable to obtain funds"
a   00002312    0   0   dorsal#2 abaxial#1  facing away from the axis of an organ or organism; "the abaxial surface of a leaf is the underside or side facing away from the stem"
```

This text is from sentiwordnet. I want to remove sentence  after a fifth tab like after word able#1 sentence should be omitted (i-e its gloss) then after another word unable#1 its gloss should be omitted.

what will be its regular expression to remove the gloss of words in sentiwordnet text file. Is there any way to do this or can someone make me a little sample/void for it?

the output should be like this :

```
a   00001740    0.125   0   able#1
a   00002098    0   0.75    unable#1
a   00002312    0   0   dorsal#2 abaxial#1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead look for # followed by digits..So the regex would be

```
(?<=#\d+)[^#]*$
```

`[^#]*` would match 0 to many characters except #

`(?<=#\d+)` would check if the particular pattern(# followed by digits) occurs before matching `[^#]*`

`$` depicts the end of string

**OR**

```
\t[^\t]+$
```

---

You can use the replace function of regex

```
input=Regex.Replace(input,regex,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
string text = @"a   00001740    0.125   0   able#1  (usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or... ";

string res = Regex.Replace(text, @"((?:[^\t]+\t){5}).+$", "$1");
```

Comment: unfortunately that wont work if there are less or more number of tabs..case 3 would not work from the above example..you can instead try `\t[^\t]+$`